# which jar file support for io class in S40-with-theme jar file

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40

I am working on nokia asha sdk2.0 using S40-with-theme.now my problem is that when i want to import following class but these classes not in S40-with-theme jar file .

These class is following

Code:

```
import com.sun.lwuit.io.ConnectionRequest;
import com.sun.lwuit.io.NetworkEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.io.NetworkManager;
import com.sun.lwuit.io.Storage;
```

Please tell me which jar file I have to import for it. I got stuck please suggest me

Thanks

Comment: These look like private classes that you shouldn't be making use of -- try the regular J2ME Networking and RMS storage classes.

Answer (score 0):

IO-Classes are in a separate Lib now. 
You should look for this jar in the LWUIT-directory
IO/IO-MIDP.jar

and add it to your project in the project dependencies (how to do this depends on the IDE you are using)